# может кто то знает бесплатную базу с музыкой и с api для добавления на сайт музыки

Tags: javascript, api, веб-сервер, поиск-api

пытаюсь найти server с музыкой пока четно может у каждого свой сервер с медиа или все же есть такие сервисы

вот пример get запроса

https://api.deezer.com/track/3135556

к сожилению сайт не дает полный доступ к треку а лиш 30 секундное предпрослушивание
preview

мне же нужен сайт каторый по get запросу отдаст мне песню/список песен которые можно вставить как src тега audio

Comment: опять на закрытие?) Невозможно дать объективный ответ?)
то есть ссылка на ресурс это не факт а мнение?) а где минусы так же не интирестно :(

Comment: Хотя бы вычитывайте текст на грамматический ошибки, перед размещением )

Comment: @Kromster ну у меня же не критические ошибки и иногда это делать лень

Comment: Вместо комментария, лучше бы правку вопроса сделали ...

Comment: @Kromster интересно и какую же часть мне править? я вот смотрю на мой вопрос и он до простоты понятен мне. Так какая часть не понятна вам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно, гугл отменили чтоли?

- https://soundcloud.com/
- https://opensourcemusic.com/free-music-list
- https://freemusicarchive.org/
- https://ambieva.com/
- https://funkwhale.audio/
- https://mugle.io/
- https://cchound.com/

Comment: Спасибо да не я уже 16 часов как гуглю)) в https://soundcloud.com/ регистрация не проходит . навалом сайтов посмотрел по пойску music api может не смог разабратся что как

Comment: fma по ходу не такой бесплатный как кажется уже -2)

Comment: пока что не копался основательно но у некоторых доков нет. Просто ради уточнения ты сам пользовался хоть одним или просто по пойску google на глаз кинул ссылки?

Comment: Ну это ссылки из закладок, не то чтобы я использовал. добавил сайт cchound.com - там точно свободная музыка, поначалу забыл про него, и очень необоснованно.

Comment: спс шя гляну с остальными не разабрался

Comment: не либо не один из этих не дает доступ к трекам либо я не смог разобраться во всяком случае спасибо я вроде нашел что надо завтра надо глянуть api